# Excel Conditional Data and Text Manipulation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing a number of columns most important of which are called `"sequence"`, `"modifications"` and `"signal"`. Column called `"sequence"` contains a number of entries, which repeat itself as long as there is different `"modification"`. Each particular sequence with given "modification" assigned certain "signal" value.

```
Sequence         Modification                Signal
ABCDEF           None                        100
ABCDEF           Carba                       200
ABCDEF           NEIAA                       300
ABCDEF           NEIAA,Carba                 400

ABCDEFG          None                        400
ABCDEFG          Carba                       600
ABCDEFG          NEIAA                       700
ABCDEFG          NEIAA, Carba                800
ABCDEFG          2XNEIAA                     900
```

The task which I am having problem with consist of clustering similar sequences with different modification together, getting a total sum of signal for this particular group , dividing signal from individual group components to the calculated sum for this particular sequence cluster, then grouping obtained percentage values to entries with and without NEIAA tag, summing values for all entries with NEIAA tag within the group and reporting it as a final `"% MODIFICATION"` value for this particular cluster.

For example Sequence "ABCDEF" have total signal of 1000 with 30% and 40% belonging to entries with NEIAA tag, thus total `% Modification` for this particular cluster is 70%. Similarly for sequence "ABCDEFG" total % MODIF is equal to `100*(700+800+900)/(400+600+700+800+900)`.

Both formula or VBA would work for me.

**My sample data is as below:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with

```
SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2)
```

you can summ all (which you allready got)

and with

```
SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,"*NEIAA*")
```

you can sum only the ones including `NEIAA`

put everything together (we want it only once at the first sequence but have it dragable) just put in `F2`

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)=0,LEN(A2)>0),SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,"*NEIAA*")/SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),"")
```

if you still have questions, just ask

`COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A2)=0` just checks to have the value in column `A` the first time and `LEN(A2)>0)` just skips the the blank cells ;)

**EDIT**:

Assuming everything is shifted to the right and column A gains a unique Keyword, so each combination of column A and B is like it is now for only column A you can try this pls: (put in G2 and then auto-fill down as you need it)

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,B2,$A$1:A1,A2)=0,LEN(B2)>0),SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,B2,C:C,"*NEIAA*",A:A,A2)/SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,B2,A:A,A2),"")
```

as said:
  - everything is shifted to the right (insert column in front of everything)
  - column A now holds the "run" -> sum up everything having the same "run" AND "sequence" (and the "NEIAA"-part)

[image: sample]

If you still have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk for solving me a lot of headache and even more time. Now what took me before a couple of hours of manual tedious work now I can do in a couple of second. This particular task was at the core

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk for solving me a lot of headache and even more time. And I do appreciate all the efforts Harun made in making this post viewable. Now what took me before a couple of hours of manual tedious work now I can do in a couple of seconds. Did not know that Excel is that powerful though I suspected that it is a matter of knowledge and experience. This particular task was at the very core of the bigger formatting task. There are a couple of steps preceding that which also could be improved. Looks like to explain it in more detail  I will need to open separate post.  Danke shoen, Dirk.

Comment: Hoi Dirk, I was trying to expand this formula on the spreadsheet where those sequences are repeating by being measured a couple of times and for some reason it only produces %modification values only in the first instance ( first measure) and upon review it was not correct value as it was summing values across all measurements and giving output only in the first. However when I removed repeat measurements everything worked fine.  Any amendments to the formula which can help ? Cheers. Victor

Comment: The formula needs to know where to start and to end the ranges for calculation. If there are multiple ranges holding the same sequence, there needs to be some kind of "difference" so the formula knows which rows to in-/exclude to/from the calculation.

Comment: The difference , different parallel measurements or "runs", is actually specified in the additional column . It is better to put it in column A actually ( in the above example), and shift everything to the right. So we will have a structure of RUN1 consisting say of those 9 entries in the example,  then directly below RUN2 of the same or a bit different entries and so on. I was trying to do it myself by introducing additional ranges in the formula, but looks like SUMIFS accept only two ranges except values. May be I just put something wrong or it is a matter of punctuation.

Comment: @HazBeck Please check my EDIT-part if it fit your needs ;)

Comment: Works like a charm. Sie sind Der Mann. Have to wait a couple of more days before they release me from the jail house to continue with the rest. Shoene woechen ende.